# How to remove space between only specific lines in unix not all the file

Tags: unix

## example:

## file name :test1

```
line1

line2
line3
line4

line5

exit
```

just i want remove space between line1 and line2 only not all lines
like this i want output

## file name :test1

```
line1
line2
line3
line4

line5

exit
```

Thanks in advance ,

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
$ cat rem_space.txt
line1

line2
line3
line4

line5

exit

$  perl -ne ' { next if /^\s*$/s and $x++==0 ; print } ' rem_space.txt
line1
line2
line3
line4

line5

exit

$
```